# what does "field release" mean in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

"Technical workshop on preparation of dossiers for field release of LMOs"

LMO= Living Modified Organism

Comment: Without a supplied context, I can only assume that within the medical context, field release means testing this "out in the real world" as opposed to "lab testing".

Answer (score 1):

It just means release into a field (a place where crops are grown).  The phrase "field release" implies that the organism is no longer being kept in an enclosed environment from which it cannot escape.